# Как выполнить HTTP Get?

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio

Добавил

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

в андроидМанифест. Функция, которую я использую:

```
public String getData(int _timeout, String _encoding, String _url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(_url).openConnection();
        connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connect.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        connect.setUseCaches(false);
        connect.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connect.setConnectTimeout(_timeout);
        connect.setReadTimeout(_timeout);
        connect.connect();

        int status = connect.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 304:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        connect.getInputStream(), _encoding));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        //код обработки ошибки
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //код обработки ошибки
    }
    return "NOTHING";
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
String test = getData(10000, "UTF-8", "http://google.com/");
```

Ошибка, которая появляется в logcat

> 05-09 18:48:35.003 22421-22421/com.test_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute
>   method of the activity at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3609)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3604)             at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)             at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)             at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)             at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)             at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1208)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388) at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239) at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
>   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
>   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239) at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
>   at com.test_app.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.java:45) at
>   com.test_app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:211)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)             at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3604)             at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)             at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)             at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)             at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)             at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @Axifive Пожалуйста, не правте метки в заголовках, просто удаляйте их, они там не нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException гуглите. Все операции с сетью должны выполняться только в отдельном потоке.